# Multiple static folders one for each client

Tags: firebase, multi-tenant, sveltekit

I am planning to extend my sveltekit app to a multi-tenancy one.
Each tenancy will have its own users, collection and hosting site in firebase.

Already implemented users authentication using gcloud identity platform

Each tenancy has different arts and different settings.
I am thinking about using one static folder for each tenancy.
Meaning instead of static folder I’ll have staticClient1, staticClient2 folders
When each folder contains the client logo and a json file with the client settings. Office Address and firebase collection, for example.

How do I build each client site?
Do I need to change kit.files: attribute in svelte.config.js per build in order to set the right “static” folder?

How do I deploy each client site?

I am using svelteAdapterFirebase to create an SSR function.
Do I need a different SSR function for each client?

Eventually I want to run these commands when adding a new client.

```
firebase hosting:sites:create client1
npm run build site=client1
npm run deploy --only hosting:client1
```

Is it the right way to do it?